# JSON schema validation in chrome packaged app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, jsonschema, ajv

I am tring to use [AJV](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) JSON schema validator in my chrome app.
But I am getting the error

> EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".

It happens during execution of

```
var validate = ajv.compile(schema);
```

As I understand AJV uses dynamic code generation and eval() to validate JSON
which is forbidden by [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy#but).

Is there a way to use AJV in chrome apps?

Or is there some other JSON schema validator which could be used in chrome apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some library that you want to use is incompatible with Chrome CSP, then you can [use it inside a sandbox](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#sandboxing).

This is [well documented](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sandbox), and has a [concrete example](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sencha_framework) and a whole dedicated article ["Using eval in Chrome Extensions. Safely."](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval)

The downside is that you can't write code that uses both Chrome API and the library. You need to separate this and communicate between two scripts.

Comment: Concrete example helped me alot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently implemented the option to precompile schemas into standalone modules with [ajv-cli](https://github.com/jessedc/ajv-cli#compile-schemas). In this way you can completely avoid using code generation and Function constructor, so you will simply comply with your CSP.

Although there are [limitations](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv-pack#limitations) compared with what can be done with Ajv itself, the majority of use cases are covered.

Comment: Updated limitations for ajv 7+: https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/blob/master/docs/standalone.md#configuration-and-limitations

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue.
Used [jsonchema](https://github.com/tdegrunt/jsonschema) instead as a drop-in replacement.
Worked ok for me.